# Using Monte Carlo to find the probability of being dealt 2 Aces when playing blackjack

Tags: r, montecarlo, blackjack

I am trying to find the probability that you are dealt 2 Aces when playing Blackjack. I am not sure on how to set up the sample function but I thought since I only have two possibles of either having two aces or not, then I'd use 1 for yes and -1 for no. I thought you would set replace equal to false since we are playing with one deck but that gave me an improper length error. If I could get some direction on where I am going wrong that be great.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
two_aces <- function(n){
  x <- sample(c(1,-1), 2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(4/52,48/52)) 
}

S <- replicate(10000, two_aces(1000))
mean(S)
mean(S > 0)
```

I computed the expected value to compare with the mean but I got -58.74 which was no where close to the mean of -0.85 from the code.

Comment: If you draw one ace with a probability of 4/52, then the probability of drawing a second ace drops to 3/51. These are not independent events. This seems to be a statistical misunderstanding not directly related to programming. You might want to consult with your instructor.

Comment: Something like `x <- sample(1:52, 2, replace = FALSE));  n_aces = sum(x <= 4)` would be a more sound approach. A couple other comments: (a) If your function takes an argument `n`, you should use `n` somewhere inside the function. (b) Why are your probabilities negative? And greater in magnitude than 1? Both of those should be read flags that something is *very* wrong.

Comment: For the exact probability I did (1*4/52)+(-1*3/51)*1000 which gave me the value of -58.78.

Comment: *Probability* is defined to be between 0 and 1. Something with probability 0 never happens. Something with probability 1 always happens. Take from that what you will.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say expected value is -58.74. For the exact probability I got (4/52)(3/51) .

Comment: (I've always preferred encoding cards with `0:51`, since `0:51 %/% 13` gives *suit* and `0:51 %% 13` gives *card* (`0` ace, `12` king). That would make `mean(replicate(100000, all((sample(0:51, size=2) %% 13) < 1)))` a good empirical estimate of the true probability. Your `(1*4/52)+(-1*3/51)*1000` makes no sense to me ... I would expect that on {0,1}, `E[2A] = (4/52)*(3/51)`, so on {-1,1} we should have `E[2A] = 2*(4/52)*(3/51)-1` (pseudo-code, not R).

Comment: @r2evans that code makes a lot of sense. When I ran the code it was very similar to my exact probability. My expected value got really messed up because the 1000 shouldn't have been there, used a bad formula. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we instead use {0,1} for the no/yes classifications, then the expected value should be

```
1*(4/52)*(3/51)
```

which is really just short-circuited from

```
1*(4/52)*(3/51) + 0*(1 - (4/52)*(3/51))
```

If we use your {-1,1} classification, we can go from that to

```
1*(4/52)*(3/51) + (-1)*(1 - (4/52)*(3/51))
(4/52)*(3/51) + (-1 + (4/52)*(3/51))
(4/52)*(3/51) + -1 + (4/52)*(3/51)
(4/52)*(3/51) + (4/52)*(3/51) - 1
2*(4/52)*(3/51) - 1
```

(It also makes sense since the spread from 1 to -1 is double (`2*`) the original range, and offset by one (`-1`).)

When I simulate cards with simple integers (sounds like I do this frequently ... not really though), I prefer encoding from `0:51` instead, since modulus-math gives us easy "suit" and "face value":

```r
0:51 %/% 13
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
0:51 %% 13
#  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  0
# [41]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

where `0` is ace and `12` is king. From this, we can randomly pull two cards and know their suit (if need be) and face value rather simply:

```r
set.seed(3)
s <- sample(0:51, size = 2)
cbind(suit = s %/% 13, face = s %% 13)
#      suit face
# [1,]    0    8  # nine of suit 0
# [2,]    3    2  # three of suit 3
```

Determining if these are both aces then can be `all(s %% 13 < 1)`.

```r
set.seed(250)
s <- sample(0:51, size = 2)
cbind(suit = s %/% 13, face = s %% 13)
#      suit face
# [1,]    1    0  # ace of suit 1
# [2,]    3    0  # ace of suit 3

all(s %% 13 < 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

So to estimate the theoretical probability, we can do

```r
set.seed(2)
mean(replicate(1000000, all((sample(0:51, size=2) %% 13) < 1)))
# [1] 0.004498
(4/52)*(3/51)
# [1] 0.004524887
```

which, in this case, is calculated the same way as the expected value when the classification is 0=no and 1=yes. To go with your {-1,1}, the expected value would be

```r
set.seed(2)
2*mean(replicate(1000000, all((sample(0:51, size=2) %% 13) < 1))) - 1
# [1] -0.991004
```

(I don't believe you should be including your sample size of 1000 in this expected value.)